# How to Run ld in Script with A Smaller Memory Footprint?

Tags: freebsd, compiling, cmake, ld, swift

I'm trying to build Swift 3 on FreeBSD. The last thing I need to do is run the build-script.

My problem is that at some point the script runs:

> Linking CXX executable bin/llvm-lto

Which consistently kills my system by using all of its 16GB memory (1GB real + 15GB swap)

After doing some research, it seems that ld consumes [ludicrous amounts of memory](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2016-July/102829.html) when in (default) debug mode.

According to the [man page](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_3.html) it can be disabled by using:

> ld --strip-debug

How would I go about enabling that option, given that I'm never actually running the command?

Comment: What build system are you using? A GNU autotools-made Makefile, or CMake or similar?  On can usually set the environment variable `LDFLAGS` to `--strip-debug`, but this is done differently in different make systems.

Comment: I believe it is CMake (specifically ninja.) Also, prior to the problem, the messages: 'ninja: no work to do', and 'llvm: using gold linker' appear. '/usr/local/bin/cmake' then runs 'linking cxx executable bin/llvm-lto'.

Comment: @BrandonBradley did you ever find a workaround or fix for this? I used Kusalananda's method, which allowed me to link bin/llvm-lto, however it then choked on linking bin/bugpoint

Comment: @EnergyNumbers Nope. If anyone has, it would still be greatly appreciated.